# Restrict node list in entity reference field based on node field

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, entities

My "Article" nodes have a "domain" field that links to a taxonomy term.
My "Article" nodes also have a repeatable "entity reference" field "more like this" that links to other "article" nodes.

How can i restrict the list in the "more like this" field to show only the nodes that have the same "taxonomy term" that the node i am currently editing ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you need a programming (PHP) or Views-Config solution?

Comment: It doesn't matter to me. maybe a PHP version could be more configurable for future use case ... but i'm open to anything :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the PHP solution you have to provide an EntityReferenceSelection Plugin. I give you an example from my "proreos" project:

```
namespace Drupal\proreos\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection\DefaultSelection
...

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'selection' entity_reference.
 *
 * @EntityReferenceSelection(
    *   id = "default:proreos",
    *   label = @Translation("proreos selection"),
    *   entity_types = {"address_entity", "anwalt_entity", "library_entity"},
    *   group = "default",
    *   weight = 1
    * )
    */
class OwnEntitiesSelection extends DefaultSelection {

  protected function buildEntityQuery($match = NULL, $match_operator = 'CONTAINS') {
      $query = parent::buildEntityQuery($match, $match_operator);
      ... your code here to modify the query ...
      ... (I do $query->condition('user_id', $currentUid);) ...
      return $query;
   }}
```

You may also need to override validateReferenceableNewEntities().
Look for more examples in the core modules.

Comment: Hello, seems to be exactly  what i am looking for, unfortunately i can't make it work.
I created a plugin "node_domain" and put src/Plugin/EntityReferenceSelection/NodeDomainSelection.php with a class  NodeDomainSelection extends DefaultSelection   but this file seems to never be loaded (plugin is activated, cache cleared, ...) any clue on how to delcare it properly ?

Comment: Hm, there is nothing special about it. Have your module activated? Have the correct annotation (@EntityReferenceSelection), have the correct psr path (src/Plugin/EntityReferenceSelection). Should work. What do you mean by "I created a plugin"? Is this a module?

Comment: Check out this known bug: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2743773